# Handle MSTSCLIB Windows Dialog C#

Tags: c#, rdp

i wrote a simple rdp connection Tool with MSTSCLIB. That works perfectly for me.

```
 //hide form border
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

    //server and username
    rdp.Server = "*********";
    rdp.UserName = "*********";

    //password
    IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
    secured.ClearTextPassword = "***********";

    //resolution
    rdp.DesktopHeight = 1080;
    rdp.DesktopWidth = 1920;

    //rdp  options
    rdp.AdvancedSettings8.AuthenticationLevel = 2;

    //connect
    rdp.Connect();
```

Sometimes the user is allready logged on to the remote workstation and I receive a Windows Dialog "The specified Windows account is already logged in. ...".

I need a solution to confirm that Windows dialog automatically. So the first idea was to set the application in foreground:

```
        //Set window as foreground window
            Process processes = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            //MessageBox.Show(processes.ProcessName);

            IntPtr windowhandle = processes.MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(windowhandle);
```

And the second step is to get the windows Handle ID with spy++ and use FindWindow() to use SendMessage() to close the MessageBox Handle.

```
//Get the MessageBox handle
            IntPtr handle = FindWindow("?????????", null);
            MessageBox.Show("Hanlde1: " + handle.ToString() + "\n");

            //Get the Text window handle
            IntPtr txtHandle = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Static",  null);
            MessageBox.Show("\ttext handle: " + txtHandle.ToString() + "\n");
            int len = GetWindowTextLength(txtHandle);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Get the text
            GetWindowText(txtHandle, sb, len + 1);
            MessageBox.Show("\ttext: " + sb.ToString() + "\n\n");

            //close the messagebox
            SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, handle), WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

So my problem is, that I can't get the Handle ID from spy++ for the Dialog in the RDP connection. It shows me only the ID from the parent Window not from the Windows Dialog.

So my first question is: Is that the correct way to handle this dialog window?
And Second Question: How can I receive the correct Handle ID of the Dialog Window in the RDP Session.

Many Thanks.

Hagen